# Finding data from all files in the folder

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, files, csv

I have folder which contains pipe(|) separated data. I want to have a list of the 8th column in first line of every file in the folder along with the file name, would be good if all this data can be consolidated in a file

Answer (score 3):

For passing files to `awk` we can use shell globstar. `-F` can be used to define field delimiter, so `-F'|'` is what we need. And as far as only getting first line, using `nextfile` is sufficient. Thus, we can do:

```
awk -F'|' '{print FILENAME,$8;nextfile}' ./*
```

from within the folder in which  files are located.

It should be noted that `nextfile` might not be supported. For instance, as Stephane noted, Debian and its derivatives ship with older version of `mawk`, which doesn't have `nextfile` as option. In the case where you need to have more portable awk code, you can take advantage of `FNR` variable. For instance:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==1{print FILENAME,$8}'  ./*
```

Comment: Though `nextfile` originated as a `gawk` extension, [it's now supported in many other `awk` implementations](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607), including `mawk` (though not the antiquated version found on Debian and derivatives). With `awk` implementations that don't support it `nextfile` would still be a harmless statement (references the `nextfile` variable), so `awk -F'|' 'FNR==8{print FILENAME, $8; nextfile}' ./*` would be portable (and more efficient with `awk`s that have `nextfile`). You need the `./*` prefix btw or it won't work for filenames containing `=` characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wait, why `FNR==8` ?  OP wanted to only process first record of each file

Comment: Sorry, typo, early morning and all. `awk -F'|' 'FNR==1{print FILENAME, $8; nextfile}'`, the point being to use `nextfile` **and** to check on FNR for those `awk`s that don't support nextfile and for which `nextfile` would be a harmless statement.

Comment: For the record (I had to check as I can't trust my memory much these days), `nextfile` was introduced in gawk 3.0.0 in 1996, renamed from `next file` added in gawk 2.14 (1992).

Answer (score 2):

Though I still prefer the [`awk` approach](/a/348846) (more legible, more shell-like, more efficient), that's one case where using a shell loop would work relatively well:

```
for file in *; do
  IFS='|' read -r x x x x x x x text x < "$file" || continue
  printf '%s\n' "$file: $text" || exit
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . ! -name . -prune -exec test -f {} \; -exec sh -c '
   printf "%s:%s\n" "$1" "$(head -q -n 1 "$1" | cut -d\| -f8)"
' {} {} \;
```